# Why didn't the Jedi send any reinforcements to Qui-Gon in Naboo to fight Darth Maul?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-phantom-menace

It seems to me that everything would have been vastly different had Qui-Gon received any reinforcements, perhaps a Knight or two, maybe a Master. This was a suspected Sith, their legendary enemy that hasn't been seen for a thousand years. Any considerable lead, especially coming from a Jedi Master, should have been dealt with the utmost priority.

Is this another evidence of how flawed and conceited the Council had become?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the Jedi council is massively overconfident in the abilities of individual Jedi and massively underestimates the power of the dark side of the Force.

> *Yoda lifted one skinny arm, pointing at Qui-Gon. “With this Naboo
> Queen, you must stay, Qui-Gon. Protect her, you must.”*
>
> ***The others murmured their approval, evidencing the confidence they
> felt in the Jedi Master’s abilities.** Still Qui-Gon said nothing.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel))</sup></sub>

They're also concerned about seeming to take sides in a local conflict between the Naboo and the Trade Federation. Qui-Gon (and his apprentice) are still, arguably, acting on the Chancellor's orders as his personal ambassadors. Adding additional Jedi would require additional approval.

> **MACE WINDU:** *Protect the Queen, but do not intercede if it comes to war until we have the Senate's approval.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Phantom Menace - Original Screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html)</sup></sub>